# multi sql command not working into PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have any sql command for create backup from table's fields and i'm using this bewlow command in phpmyadmin:

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM sale_khomsi;
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id= NULL , faal= 1;
INSERT INTO sale_khomsi SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

this work correctly but after runing this command into php code such az:

**PHP:**

```
$reslut=mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM sale_khomsi;
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id= NULL , faal= 1;
INSERT INTO sale_khomsi SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;");
```

not working .

**result of MYSQL into PHPMYADMIN:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM sale_khomsi;# 4 rows affected.
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id= NULL , faal= 1;# 4 rows affected.
INSERT INTO sale_khomsi SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;# 4 rows affected.
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Comment: Just a side note might want to change `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` or something else like `pdo`

Comment: you can not execute multiple statement in single mysql_query();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin uses ; as a delimiter between calls to the database. Therefore entering that string in phpMyAdmin will cause 4 queries to run, not one massive query as you have. You need to break it down.

```
$result = mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM sale_khomsi");

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id= NULL , faal= 1");  

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale_khomsi SELECT * FROM tmptable_1");

$result = mysql_query("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1");
```

That should give you the desired result. Of course you need to check the outcome of result to make sure the query was successful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for executing multi-query in mysql. But if you go for mysqli it is there.

```
mysqli_multi_query()
```

But if want to use mysql only mean you can go for procedure for these kind of things.